# .NET 6 on Arch Linux: User Secrets not being read

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am working in a .NET 6 application on Arch Linux. The [code is open-source](https://github.com/jwankhalaf/bejebeje).

I am certain that `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `Development` because I updated the code in my `Program.cs` to be:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

  // the default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
  app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("We are in development environment!!!");
}
```

And when I run the application with `dotnet run --project Bejebeje.Mvc/Bejebeje.Mvc.csproj` I can see my above message.

In my `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` I don't have any variables set.

I do have user-secrets set. When I run `dotnet user-secrets list --project Bejebeje.Mvc` I get:

```
Sentry__SendDefaultPii = true
Sentry__MinimumEventLevel = Warning
Sentry__MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = Debug
Sentry__IncludeRequestPayload = true
Sentry__Dsn = https://blah@blah.ingest.sentry.io/blah
Sentry__DiagnosticsLevel = Error
Sentry__Debug = true
Sentry__AttachStackTrace = true
IdentityServerConfiguration__ClientSecret = blah
IdentityServerConfiguration__ClientId = blah
IdentityServerConfiguration__Authority = https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-blah/
ConnectionString = Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=bejebeje;User Id=postgres;Password=admin;
```

Yet when I run the application with `dotnet run --project Bejebeje.Mvc/Bejebeje.Mvc.csproj` I get:

```
We are in development environment!!!
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/j/code/bejebeje/Bejebeje.Mvc/
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.ArgumentException: Options.ClientId must be provided (Parameter 'ClientId')
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions.Validate()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.Validate(String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSchemeHelper>b__1(TOptions o)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ValidateOptions`1.Validate(String name, TOptions options)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
         at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
         at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
         at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
         at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Sentry.AspNetCore.SentryTracingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in /_/src/Sentry.AspNetCore/SentryTracingMiddleware.cs:line 106
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

It can't find the [ClientId here](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje/blob/main/Bejebeje.Mvc/Program.cs#L25). I even debugged in Rider, and I can see that when I go past that line, ClientId is indeed `null`.

What am I missing? I've been struggling with this for the past 2 days and I can't figure out why my user secrets aren't being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `user-secrets` - you should separate sections with a colon (`:`) instead of a double-underscore (`__`).
It is a bit confusing, I know, but double underscores are used for environment variables, whereas user secrets are not actually environment variables.
You can see [MSDN's examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=linux#read-the-secret-via-the-configuration-api) reflect this.

Comment: I swear I had tried the colon as separator too and previously it didn't work, but I just tried now and it worked! I'm not sure what's going on, but I'm happy that things are finally working. Much appreciated.

Comment: All of a sudden, it doesn't work again, even though I have `:` as the separator.